# jQuery callback return true/false for onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have implemented some basic ajax for loading pages via an `onclick` of the `<a>` tag.

The problem is that my JS is not returning to the `onclick` its `bool` val, here is my JS/jQuery and my HTML, I am sure it is a small oversight on my behalf but its driving me nuts.

JS:

```
function loadPage (caller) {
  var href = $(caller).attr('href');
  var url = 'http://localhost/api';

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url + href,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
      $('li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(caller).parent().addClass('active');
      $('div#content').html(data);
      history.pushState({foo: "bar"} , '', href);
      return false;
    },
    error: function () {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a class="header-text" href="/" onclick="return loadPage(this);"></a></li>
```

In case anyone is wondering I am doing this so that the button will ajax the content, and if the js fails for some reason it will instead load the page fully.

Comment: Not possible. Instead, always cancel it and manually redirect on error.

Comment: You should add `href='#', and use asynchronous api calls and show your data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure complete loading. You can use the following code

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/